# isolated child element of flex box items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: red;
}

.child-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child-child-content {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav">
      Navigation
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child-content">
        <div class="child-child-content">
          I want this is scrollable and don't break size of child-content. But it don't work.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want child-child-item element is isolated, don't affect child-item size, and break overal layout.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRdLJX)

I know can fix it by absolute position, but I don't know if that is the best solution for my problem.

Sorry for my english skill.
Help me, thanks!

Comment: how about setting  overflow on the flex child instead ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmKBmZ . position:absolute is also a good approach, it takes off element off the flow and allow to size it from it's position:relative parent

Comment: So what is the problem then, that absolute positioning does not solve?

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, I want to try with only flex box. Now, I add Toolbar. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKWdRp, I use overflow for flex item, but it don't work. Help me.

Comment: is this a new question ? i do not see any toolbar :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKWdRp , I use nested flex box to add toolbar panel, and I continue isolated content-container div, I set content-container is overflow (content-container is a flex item), but it isn't work. :(

Comment: okay, here is the approach for static elements. you need to dispatch overflow and reset height on column flex box https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWxKbQ Now your answer is : overflow or absolute works when absolute is the easiest/fastest to handle and to avoid difference cross-browsers

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, your patch is very very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

it is good also to use absolute position. if you found another way please spread it.